# Conditional Anchor tag and on-click

Tags: angularjs

Given a list of objects defined as a name and linkid, if linkid is null I just want to show the name, if linkid has a value I want to wrap the name in an anchor tag and bind to a click event.  So for example object A is:

```
objectA {
    name: "Object A"
}
```

I want to display on the page just as text, so I can use:

```
{{objectA.name}}
```

However, given objectB as:

```
objectB {
    name: "Object B",
    linkId: 3
}
```

I want the markup to be:

```
<a href="#" ng-click="clickEvent(objectB.linkId)">{{objectB.name}}</a>
```

How would I do this using angularjs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A very simple solution would be to use Angular's built-in directives:

```
<a ng-if="objectB.linkId" href ng-click="clickEvent(objectB.linkId)">{{ objectB.name }}</a>
<span ng-if="!objectB.linkId">{{ objectB.name }}</span>
```

This does create an extra `span` element when the object has no `linkId`, but is a simple solution.